# Should we freeze the number of people coming in to the study for Kaplan-Meier test

Tags: kaplan-meier

I'm conducting a Kaplan Meier study to determine user retention for a website. I'm planning to limit my timeline to 6 months and see how many users are dropping within that time period. And if a user does not have any action for a month I'm considering that as an event. But I keep seeing new users. What should I do in that case? Limit the users in my study to all the users I see in the first month?

Comment: I gather your drop-out event is inaction for a month. But what if a user comes back on-line a few weeks later? Do you consider that a new user? Or do  you erase the drop-out event? So does "survival" mean some kind of user activity within the last 4 weeks of the end of your trial? You'll have to be explicit about how you handle dropping out and re-upping. You could also study the distribution of dwell times between visits to the site. If you fit the low end to a common distribution, you could have a data-defined "death event dwell time" (6 weeks? 8 weeks?) to use with the survival study.

Comment: At first, the the definition of beginning is needed to calculate the survival time for K-M method.For example, it can be the the time the user opens his account.

Answer (score 5):

Do not use calendar time to display the Kaplan Meier curve. Rather, take the time at which a user establishes an account, or first navigates to the site (or whatever data you have) as time 0.